# How to implement a lowpass filter for this one zero, one pole transfer function?

Tags: circuit-design, filter, transfer-function, low-pass

I have a task where I need to implement a filter circuit (active) for the following transfer function:

$$G(s)=\frac{(s-5447)}{(s-961.3)}$$

So, we have one pole and one zero. The bode plot is as below (dB/Hz):
[image: Bode plot of G(s)]

However, I can't for the life of me seem to design a circuit to implement it. A simple RC filter doesn't have any zeroes, and everything else I've tried (such as the circuit on page 12 of [this document](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gari/teaching/b18/background_lectures/1P2-Op-Amp-Circuits-L2-Notes-Collins.pdf)) leaves me stuck with terms involving negative real values or \$-\frac{1}{s}\$ which don't map to a real component. (My reasoning is that resistors contain positive real components, inductors \$sL\$ and capacitors \$\frac{1}{sC}\$.

I'm not sure if I'm just solving this kind of equation incorrectly, or if I'm using "bad" topologies to approach this specific transfer function. How would you go about implementing it? Using op-amps is completely fine.

*(For context, my circuit needs to reverse the effect of an unknown, "black box" filter. I got my gain function by figuring out the black box's transfer function and inverting it.)*

Comment: *A simple RC filter doesn't have any zeroes* Hmm, so a high-pass section in an RC filter doesn't have any zeros? There are methods for synthesizing RC / RLC networks from transfer functions. You should study a book on the subject.

Comment: Did you derive the TF from the bode plot?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, using a calculated value for the pole and zero.

Comment: Are you sure about the pole in the right-half plane?

Comment: I had exactly the same question as Chu asked: the roots for the numerator and the denominator are positive: you have a right-half-plane zero (RHPZ) and a right-half-plane pole (RHPP). The RHPZ can be implemented in an all-pass filter but certainly not the RHPP which would lead to an instable system. Besides, if you factor 5447 and 961, the leading term is 5.66 indicating that this expression describes a system with gain at dc: cannot be implemented with simple \$RC\$ elements and an active circuit is needed.

Comment: Looks like a 1st order RC:RC LPF with 15dB attend at extremes of about 5% with 120 Hz HPF and 1kHz LPF ballpark

Comment: @Chu Indeed, I've double checked by plotting this particular function and comparing it to my measured values.

Comment: @VerbalKint I'm fine with using active elements e.g. op-amps, just unsure how to actually construct it

Comment: The thing is that you can't have a RHPP in the transfer function, the output of your filter would diverge. If you have measured something in the bench, then you don't have a RHPP and you should check the signs in your equation. It should probably be \$s+...\$ in the denominator. Can you please show the phase response as well, it will tell the polarity of the roots.

Comment: @VerbalKint Wow, I guess you're right. For some reason I had the idea that if I had the wrong sign then the bode plot would be different, but of course only the phase plot would change...

Comment: Ok, so the correct expression is \$G(s)=\frac{s+5447}{s+961.3}\$ then?

Comment: Plugging in \$s=j\omega\$ does not show up the problem. If you do the inverse Laplace transform you'll find the impulse response goes to infinity.

Comment: ... a necessary condition for substituting \$\small s\rightarrow j\omega\$ is that there are no poles in the right half plane.

Comment: @Chu, plotting the magnitude/phase response will certainly show the system is non-minimum phase with well-spread pole and zero. When the pole kicks in, having a phase going up indicates the presence of the RHP pole. I however agree that it is easy in a two-root transfer function and it would be a less obvious exercise with a higher-order denominator (or numerator with more RHP zeroes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is to rewrite your transfer function in the proper *low-entropy* way, with a leading term. I have assumed the roots are all negative leading to left-half-plane pole and zero:

\$G(s)=\frac{s+5447}{s+961.3}=G_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ where:

\$G_0=\frac{5447}{961.3}=5.66\$

\$\omega_z=5447\$ rd/s or 867 Hz

\$\omega_p=961.3\$ rd/s or 153 Hz

There are plenty of ways to implement such a filter. One way is to use an op-amp in an inverting configuration and have it followed by another inverting structure with a gain of -1:

[image]

You then calculate the values of the various components according to the below Mathcad sheet. These values can be determined using fast analytical techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371).

[image]